# ADO Text Driver Trimming Leading Space

Tags: vba, adodb, text-parsing

I'm using ADODB with the Microsoft Text Driver to parse a text file in Excel.

The problem is that some lines of the file have a leading space, and this leading space is getting chopped.

When I do a GetString(,1) on my recordset, a line like:
" description DO NOT USE"

gets trimmed to:

"description DO NOT USE"

...this is problematic because I'm actually parsing a Cisco config file, and the leading space is useful in figuring out if I'm still in the same object or not.

For example with text like:

```
object-group network ABC_Group
 network-object host 192.10.24.71
 network-object host 192.10.24.72
 network-object host 192.10.24.20
 network-object host 192.10.24.21
object-group network XYZ_hosts
 network-object host 192.10.24.55
 network-object host 192.10.24.26
```

...I am using the leading space to tell me that I am still in the same object-group.

Any ideas on how to get ADODB to keep the leading space when it reads the text file?

I initially tried using just the FileStreamObject, but discovered that the file I was reading had some lines ending in Chr(13) and some ending in both Chr(13) and Chr(10), which was throwing off the Readline method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, earlier version of this answer used C#.  For VBA, you have to do a little more heavy lifting.

If the file is small enough to fit in memory, you could read the whole thing in as a string, and then split it:

```
Private Function SplitFileContents(ByVal fileContents As String) As String()

    Dim arrResult() As String
    Dim resultCount As Long
    Dim crPos As Long
    Dim lfPos As Long
    dim endPos As Long

    Do While Len(fileContents) > 0
        crPos = InStr(fileContents, vbCr)
        lfPos = InStr(fileContents, vbLf)

        If crPos = 0 And lfPos = 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve arrResult(0 To resultCount)
            arrResult(resultCount) = fileContents
            resultCount = resultCount + 1
            Exit Do
        ElseIf crPos = 0 Then
            endPos = lfPos
        ElseIf lfPos = 0 Then
            endPos = crPos
        ElseIf crPos < lfPos Then
            endPos = crPos
        Else
            endPos = lfPos
        End If

        If endPos > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve arrResult(0 To resultCount)
            arrResult(resultCount) = Left$(fileContents, endPos - 1)
            resultCount = resultCount + 1
        End If

        If endPos = Len(fileContents) Then
            fileContents = ""
        Else
            fileContents = Mid$(fileContents, endPos + 1)
        End If
    Loop

    If resultCount = 0 Then
        ReDim arrResult(0 to 0)
        arrResult(0) = ""
    End If

    SplitFileContents = arrResult
End Function
```

Alternatively, there are several possible approaches using the fixed-width format, which would preserve leading spaces.  These articles discuss using the schema.ini file to specify a fixed-width file format:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187670

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/initializing-the-text-data-source-driver-HP001032166.aspx

Comment: Out of those, I think the fixed-width possibility shows the most promise...theoretically then if rst!Column1 = null and rst!Column2 <> null then you would be able to see that there was a leading space. I've since refactored to use the text as cues instead of the spaces.

Comment: That's probably the best approach, anyway: Deciding what you're looking at by how it looks, not by where it's located.